# If a method logically has to return a value, should I return a default to satisfy the compiler error that not all code paths return a value?

Tags: c#, async-await

The below method produces this compile error:

> 'SqlDeadlockHelper.ExecuteAsync(Func<Task>)': not all code paths return a value

I don't think it's logically possible for that to be true, based on the contents of the method. If I add `return default` as the last line, I'm good (or perhaps I should throw an exception). Should I be getting this error?

```
    public static async Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> func)
    {
        int tryCount = 0;

        do
        {
            try
            {
                tryCount++;
                return await func();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                bool isRetryException = IsRetrySqlException(ex);
                bool retryHasBeenExhausted = tryCount >= MaxRetries;

                if (!isRetryException) { throw; }

                if (retryHasBeenExhausted) { throw new SqlHelperException("message here", ex); }

                // Logging here
            }

            // Wait for a period of time before retrying.
            SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => false, RetryDelayInMilliseconds);
        }
        while (tryCount <= MaxRetries);

        //return default; // This solves the problem, but logically we can't ever get here.
    }
```

This is the other, synchronous, method in its entirety. I can clean it up to remove the parts we deem irrelevant, but here is the whole thing for now.

```
    protected void ExecuteWithExceptionRetry(params SqlExceptionNumber[] sqlExceptionNumbers)
    {
        // determine the exception numbers to retry
        List<SqlExceptionNumber> retryExceptionNumbers = new List<SqlExceptionNumber>(this._exceptionNumbers);
        if ((sqlExceptionNumbers != null) && (sqlExceptionNumbers.Count() > 0))
        {
            retryExceptionNumbers.Clear();
            retryExceptionNumbers.AddRange(sqlExceptionNumbers);
        }

        // make sure there are retry exceptions to look for
        if (retryExceptionNumbers.Count == 0)
        {
            retryExceptionNumbers.AddRange(from SqlExceptionNumber e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SqlExceptionNumber)) where e.IsDefault() select e);
        }

        int tryCount = 0;
        int maxRetries = this.MaxRetryCount;

        do
        {
            try
            {
                // increment the try count...
                tryCount++;

                this.Action();
                
                return; // If here, execution was successful, so we can return.
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                bool isRetryException = IsRetrySqlException(exception, retryExceptionNumbers.ToArray());
                bool hasRetryBeenExhausted = tryCount >= maxRetries;

                if (!isRetryException)
                    throw;

                if (hasRetryBeenExhausted)
                {
                    throw new SqlRetryHelperRetryExceededException(
                        string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                            "SQL exception thrown during query execution, retries have been exhausted after {0} attempt(s).",
                            maxRetries),
                        exception);
                }

                // need to keep retrying so log the current exception and keep going
                string details = (this.LogRetryDetails)
                    ? string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Exception Detail: {0}", exception.ToString())
                    : string.Empty;

                string errorMessage = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    "SQL exception thrown during query execution, will try {0} more time(s). {1}", maxRetries - tryCount, details);
                _logger.Warning(errorMessage);
            }

            // wait for a period of time before retrying
            if (this.RetryDelayInMilliseconds.HasValue)
            {
                SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => false, this.RetryDelayInMilliseconds.Value);
            }
        }
        while (tryCount <= maxRetries);
    }
```

Comment: If you have elaboration, **edit the post**. Comments are for requesting clarification, not for the original author to add information. As for the question, you have lots of options, and which should be used is mainly a matter of opinion. _My_ opinion is that your `while` loop should be infinite. If you are confident that the loop cannot exit due to the condition, then what's the point of the condition? Alternatively, you could throw an exception after the loop, which would satisfy the compiler while giving you a backstop on your logic. I think returning a default value is the worst option.

Comment: As for _"Should I be getting this error?"_, that's a whole separate question, one which has been answered many times on Stack Overflow already. Short version: yes. The compiler has very clear rules about when such warnings are emitted, and your code qualifies for the error. Compiler execution flow analysis is necessarily not able to identify every possible scenario, even if you feel through your own analysis proves the code past the loop is unreachable.

Comment: Why even have a condition that you check if you're 100% certain that it will always return true?  Why execute code that, if it were to ever evaluate to anything other than `true`, would be a bug for you?

Comment: @Servy Are you suggesting a `for` loop instead?

Comment: @BobHorn How would using a `for` loop prevent you from performing a condition that is always supposed to resolve to a constant value?

Comment: I just want to execute the loop up to 5 times, until the func runs without error, or we throw an error in the catch block, or we hit 5 iterations. I actually copied this code from another class. It's basically identical except that this method calls an async func instead of just a func. The other method doesn't have this compile error.

Comment: @BobHorn perhaps you could share the other method so we can point out what the key difference is causing this error?

Comment: @Klaycon I just added the original method to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that this method can't logically ever exit the loop is dependent on conditions and logic that will execute at runtime. The compiler does not look at these when determining what code paths are possible - it doesn't simulate the values or compare conditions to find that one will never, ever, ever be false (as in your do..while condition).

```cs
//does not compile
public static int A()
{
    int a = 1;
    do
    {
        if(a > 0) return a;
    } while(a > 0);
}
```

We know that `a > 0` cannot *ever* be false, but the compiler doesn't. But if we replace it with `true` the compiler accepts it:

```cs
//compiles
public static int A()
{
    int a = 1;
    do
    {
        if(a > 0) return a;
    } while(true);
}
```

So all you need to do in your case is replace the condition you *know* will never be false, with the literal `true` so that the compiler can be sure the loop really will never exit without returning something.

---

To answer the title question also:

> should I return a default to satisfy the compiler error that not all code paths return a value?

As expressed in the comments, this is the worst solution. You clearly expect the code to never, ever reach the end - so if it does, something has happened that your code is not prepared for. Throw an exception!

---

From comments:

> I actually copied this code from another class. It's basically identical except that this method calls an async func instead of just a func. The other method doesn't have this compile error.

Your other method has a `void` return type, so the compiler isn't checking that all code paths explicitly return.

Answer (score 1):

One day the universe will improve the idiot it passes into your idiotproof logic, MaxRetries will be less than tryCount and the do loop won't..

..then you'll be on a code path you're certain was never going to happen

You might assert you have some code somewhere that prevents each of these variables from ever being such that MaxRetries is lower than tryCount, but C# doesn't think that deeply about the code; it just foresees a possibility that this loop may not run because it's controlled by a couple of variables. You might be able to point out that MaxRetries is an int with a controlled range, and if it has "this value", and tryCount has "that value" then this bool with be blah, and that bool will be blahblah, which means that it will have to loop around.. You're already far deeper into thinking about all the possibilities of what might be happening elsewhere, than C# will do with its analysis.

But let's say that you're satisfied it'll never happen.. And then the new kid your company hires changes the MaxRetries property so it returns a random number every time its called and suddenly it's very possible that your "never get there" code path does actually get there in a lot of cases. C# still stopped short of considering anything that deeply; it doesn't look at every place in the code where it is assigned, or used, or all the possible values it can have and whether you're using a subset of them that means the end of this method can never be hit

This is what throwing an exception is for; if you're certain that the only way the code could ever reach that point is if a developer screwed something up, or a user enters a value so wild you could never have imagined how to handle it.. Throw an exception that lets them know so they can fix the config etc easily

Throwing an exception is an acceptable alternative to returning a default (probably null), and entirely preferable if you're looking through logs to find why your neverfail code is failing.. Seeing an exception of "It is supposed to be impossible to reach this point; tryCount is x and MaxRetries is y. Investigate why" in a log is better than "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" X hours and Y method calls away from where the null was generated

From the comments you want to try something up to maxretries times, it would be more readable to structure the count like this:

```
    public static async Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> func)
    {

        for(int tryCount = 0; tryCount < MaxRetries; tryCount++)
        {
            try
            {
                return await func();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if(!IsRetrySqlException(ex))
                   throw;
            }

            // Wait for a period of time before retrying.
            SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => false, RetryDelayInMilliseconds);
        }
        
        //retries exhausted
        throw new SqlHelperException("message here", ex);
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear how this answers the question. I agree with the sentiment, but the fact is that given the code shown, even if `MaxRetries` is ever initialized to be less than `tryCount`, execution cannot fall out of the loop as a consequence. Either the method will return or will throw an exception. The issue is less about coding errors and more about the limits of compiler's ability to do static analysis. And the _question_ is asking for an _opinion_ about how to address the compiler error.

Comment: @PeterDuniho If `MaxRetries` is initialized to less than `tryCount`, then we would indeed fall out of the loop. The `while` condition wouldn't be met in that case.

Comment: @Bob: the condition for the loop only matters if execution can get to the _end_ of the loop. That's the whole point of `do`/`while`. The code cannot reach the end of the loop if the operation succeeds (its result is returned), nor if it fails (the `catch` block will throw an exception if `MaxRetries` is less than `tryCount`). Either way, execution doesn't reach the end of the loop, so the condition of the loop is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the same check twice. One check should be enough. My suggestion is to refactor this:

```
do
{
    //... (throws in case tryCount >= MaxRetries)
}
while (tryCount <= MaxRetries);
```

...to this:

```
while (true)
{
    //... (throws in case tryCount >= MaxRetries)
}
```

Comment: I think there are cleaner ways to write this than `while(true){ i++; if(i>x)break;}` - i.e. if you want a controlled loop, while(true)ing it and arranging complicated manual breaks is less readable than using a designed-for-it loop

Comment: @CaiusJard if you `break` from the `while` block, then you will have to return some value or throw some exception below. The OP wants to avoid that.

Comment: That's not really what i'm talking about. I'm objecting to the use of `while(true)` to do what should be done as a for loop (preferentially) or a while loop with a sensible condition. Recommending while(true) is just adding more ugly/unreadable to what is already ugly/unreadable. You don't write `int i = 0; while(true){ i++; if(i>x)break;}`, you write `int i = 0;while(i<=x){ i++; }`  or (better) `for(int i=0; i<=x;i+){ }` - what starts out with `while(true)` looks like *oh that code runs forever*, changes its mind but you have to read the whole loop to find out why; i.e. it's not readable!

Comment: @CaiusJard this is a matter of preference. Personally I am well accustomed at using `while (true)` in all sorts of (non-trivial) cases. If you think about it, having a loop that exits conditionally at the start or the end of each iteration is a special case. The general case is to check the condition anywhere inside the loop. I just did a quick search inside my notes, and I have used `while (true)` 85 times in my answers here in SO.

Comment: Suppose the task were "iterate over an array". No-one would write that as `int i = 0;while(true){ if(!i<array.Length) break; /*code*/ i++; }`, they'd write `for(int i=0; i<array.Length;i++){ /*code*/ }`, heck VS even has a snippet for it. I'm not sure I can accept "I've used while(true) all over the place so it must be ok" as valid reasoning. OP is looking for a refactor to make some code more logical and readable. Slapping a `while(true)` on top of convolution doesn't do that, it just shuts the compiler up. You *can* do anything with code but just because you can doesn't mean you *should*

Comment: @CaiusJard for me the `while (true)` denotes that I want to make my conditional exit checks in the middle of the loop. It has nothing to do with pleasing the compiler. But OK, I get it that you don't like it, and that you consider it to be ugly, illogical and unreadable.

Comment: I understand you, but the OP here has said (in comments) he's looking for a way to retry method X up to 5 times (say) - again I don't think you personally would receive that as a requirements spec and write `int i = 0; while(true){ if(i >5)break; else MethodX(); i++ }`, I genuinely think you'd write `for(int i=0; i<5; i++) MethodX();`

Comment: @CaiusJard actually I have wrote myself [code similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62782560/proper-implementation-of-async-retry-method/62783968#62783968) to OP's code (a method the invokes and retries another method until a condition occurs), and I used `while (true)`, not a `for` loop. IMHO the `for` is excellent for enumerating arrays and lists, but for loops with complex exit conditions I don't think it's suitable. Let's agree that our preferences are different. :-)